# Why does changing the file extension of an XML file break its XSL transformation?

Tags: xml, stylesheet, content-type, xslt

I have created a XML to HTML solution using XSLT, but the server I am storing the files on sets the content-disposition to "attachment" in the HTTP response header for XML files. Consequently, the browser attempts to download the XML files as attachments instead of running the XSL transformation and displaying the HTML result in the browser. Unfortunately, changing the content-disposition to "inline" is not an option for me.

Changing the XML file extension to HTML was the first workaround I considered, but it only appears to work properly in IE, and only online (not offline). I don't understand this.

Can anyone tell me why renaming the file extension breaks the XSL transformation, and is there anything I can do to either the XML or XSL content to allow me to use this workaround? Thank you.

The first few lines of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="includes/portal.xsl"?>
```

The first few lines of my XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
```

Comment: It's not mandatory for any XML consumer to honor the not quite standard stylesheet processing instruction. When using browser client side transformations, you must send the XML documents with proper content type header (`text/xml` or `application/xml`). Check my old XML/client side XSLT driven [site](http://www.aranedabienesraices.com.ar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is surely due to the returned content types returned by the server based on the file extension. What server are you using? Usually there is a way to configure the content type in other ways for specific files, directories or extensions. 
As a quick and easy check, try using the about using the .XHTML extension instead of .HTML or .XML.

Comment: The content type returned in the HTTP response header is "text/xml". I know that the problem is being caused by the content-disposition, which is "attachment". The only file types that this server sets the content-disposition to "inline" for are HTML files, so XHTML does not work either.  I wish I could do something about this, but unfortunately I have no control over this server. I am more interested to know why renaming the extension also breaks it when I open the file directly from my local file system.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong, the content type is "text/html" after I change the file extension.  Coupled with Alejandro's response above, the reasons for the behavior I am seeing are a bit more clear.